# how to insert other object to event listener?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

this is my javascript :

```
var tool = {
    addEvent : function(element, eventName, callback){
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
        }          
    },
    getPosition : function(el){
        var _x = 0;
        var _y = 0;
        while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
            _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
            _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
            el = el.offsetParent;
        }
        return { top: _y, left: _x };
    }
}
function getObj(){
    this.a = document.getElementById('div');
    this.b = document.getElementById('table');


    this.func = function(){
        var pos = tool.getPosition(this);
        // how to insert this.b here
        // i want to set this.b offset from this.a offset
    }

    tool.addEvent(this.a,'scroll',this.func);
}

var obj = new getObj();
```

how to modify this.func so whenever this.a is scrolling, this.b will be syncronized to this.a
this.b offset is get from this.a offset.

when i try :

```
 this.func = function(){
        var pos = tool.getPosition(this);
        // value from pos will be set to this.b
        console.log(this.b);
        // how to insert this.b here
        // i want to set this.b offset from this.a offset
 }
```

this.b is undefined.

Comment: i still cannot insert this.b to my func, could you help me @Bergi ??

Comment: `tool.getPosition(e.target)` and `tool.addEvent(…, this.func.bind(this))` should be working

Comment: just for my knowledge, how to change bind to call @Bergi, bind work awesome but call only work on once, but call will not work for next scroll.

Comment: What do you mean? `(function(context){return function(e){return context.func.call(context,e);};}(this))`?

Comment: haha work great and awesome .. now it work to my IE6 @Bergi , how to appreciate your answer? i want to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPosition` function is a member of `this`, so you cannot call it using `getPosition(...)`. You must call it using `this.getPosition(...)` or redeclare the `getPosition` function as a function scope variable:

```
function getObj() {
    ...
    var getPosition = function(...) { ... };

    this.addEvent = function(...) { ... };
    ...
}
```

Edit:

When adding the DOM event, you'll also need bind `this.func` to the current context:

```
this.func = this.func.bind(this);
```

this.addEvent(this.a,'scroll',this.func);

Comment: i update my question, i want help particularly, how to insert this.b to my this.func @Greg Burghardt ?